# Counting the number of words of a given text file

Tags: c, string, file

I wrote a program to count the number of words in a text file. It works well with single file lines but the problem is that when I read files which have newlines, it gives the wrong result. For example if I read myfile.txt as:

```
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

My program counts this as 4 words instead of 16. Any suggestions on how to fix?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* txtFile = NULL; // File Pointer
    int fileNUM = 0; // Data value from file
    char str[1000000];
    int count = 0, i, len, ignoreSpace;

    // Assigns the text file to txtFile
    txtFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (txtFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file"); // Couldnt find .txt file
        return -1; // -1 indicates error
    }

    // Can now use fscanf(inFile, ...) like scanf()
    fgets(str, 1000000, txtFile); 
    len = strlen(str);
    ignoreSpace = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            if (!ignoreSpace)
            {       
                count++;
                ignoreSpace = 1;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            ignoreSpace = 0;
        }
    }
    if (!ignoreSpace)
        count++;

    printf("There are %i word(s) in %s\n", count, argv[1]);

    fclose(txtFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: RTFM: fgets() reads only one line from the file.

Comment: `fgets(str, 1000000, txtFile);` --> `while(fgets(str, 1000000, txtFile)){ ` and `if (!ignoreSpace)
        count++;` --> `if (!ignoreSpace)
        count++; }//end while`

Comment: You need to call fgets() in a loop, so that you read each line.  You're actually just counting the 4 words on the first line.  Thanks @horns

Comment: You don't need `fgets` or a string buffer for this task *at all*, so I'm not sure why you're using one. Looping the file consuming whitespace, consuming non-whitespace, bumping the word count, all the while monitoring for EOF to break the loop should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) only reads up until the first newline is met or the buffer is filled.

If you want to read all the lines in your file, utilize the fact that fgets returns NULL when it can not read anything more as BLUEPIXY points out in his comment:

```
while (fgets(str, 1000000, txtFile))
{
    len = strlen(str);
    ignoreSpace = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            if (!ignoreSpace)
            {       
                count++;
                ignoreSpace = 1;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            ignoreSpace = 0;
        }
    }
    if (!ignoreSpace)
        count++;
}
```

Comment: With such a huge buffer it may be more effective to read in binary mode and checking for either a space or newline.

Answer (score 2):

`fgets(str, 1000000, txtFile);` only reads 1 line, not the entire file.

A simple solution counts the number of times a word begins.

```
long long count = 0
int PreviousWasSpace = 1;
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(txtFile) != EOF) {
  if (isspace(ch) {
    PreviousWasSpace = 1;
  } else {
    if (PreviousWasSpace) count++;
    PreviousWasSpace = 0;
  }
}
```

Note: No line length limits.  Multiple spaces between words does not cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of good approaches to this problem. The following makes use of `getline` to read lines from `stdin`. This is one of my favorite methods. Note: you can replace the check for `tab` and `space` by including `ctype.h` and using the `isspace()` function to cover additional whitespace characters. The choice below was intentional to prevent the need for additional header files:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char *line = NULL;  /* pointer to use with getline ()  */
    char *p = NULL;     /* pointer to parse getline return */
    ssize_t read = 0;   /* actual chars read per-line      */
    size_t n = 0;       /* max chars to read (0 - no limit)*/
    int spaces = 0;     /* counter for spaces and newlines */
    int total = 0;      /* counter for total words read    */

    while ((read = getline (&line, &n, stdin)) != -1) 
    {
        /* strip trailing '\n' or '\r' */
        while (line[read-1] == '\n' || line[read-1] == '\r')
            line[--read] = 0;

        spaces = 0;
        p = line;

        if (read > 0) {                   /* read = 0 covers '\n' case (blank line)  */
            while (*p) {                            /* for each character in line      */
                if (*p == '\t' || *p == ' ') {      /* if space,       */
                    while (*p == '\t' || *p == ' ') /* read all spaces */
                        p++;
                    spaces += 1;                    /* consider sequence of spaces 1   */
                } else
                    p++;                            /* if not space, increment pointer */
            }
            total += spaces + 1;                    /* words per-line = spaces + 1     */
        }
    }

    printf ("\n  Total words read: %d\n\n", total);

    return 0;

}
```

**output**

```
$ ./bin/countwordsfile <dat/captnjack.txt

  Total words read: 16
```